# Creating a wifi access point using windows 7

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ad-hoc-network, virtual-wifi

I want to allow my tablet to browse the website I'm hosting on my development machine. Since this setup is also going to be demonstrated in a conference, I would like to establish the strongest Wifi connection available.

I tried the hostednetwork interface and the ad-hoc connection, but both seem unstable for production use, at least for now.

Can I create a true access point using the wireless chip embedded on my motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wifi network using Windows 7 using [Connectify Software](http://www.connectify.me/).

All you need is you must have wifi adapter in your desktop or laptop and wifi can be used for internet access or LAN sharing.

```
Install the Connectify software. Open the software and configure it. 
Use Sharing Mode : Wifi
You can share Internet to your Wifi Network using a Source like Ethernet, data card.
```

[image]